# Avoid lines with single quotes (comment line) in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to extract all the constants, their scope, datatype etc in .VB files using regular expressions. I am using the regular expression:-

`(\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)`

and when I tested it on a .vb file, I get following results:-

```
Public Const DOT As String = "."
'Private Const SW_HIDE As Short = 0
```

I want to avoid the lines that are commented (second one in this example). For that I have modified the regular expression as:-

```
[^'](\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)
```

But it is still giving the commented lines in output. Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What language is your regex checking code in? VB.NET also?

Comment: Yes. Here are my two lines of code am using:-  `Dim strPattern As String = "(\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)"  Dim oRegEx As Regex = New Regex(strPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)`

Comment: Have you tried a negative lookbehind? Edit: also, test your Regexes here first: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Am working on regular expressions for the first time. Could you please let me know what a negative lookbehind is?

Comment: You shouldn't need lookbehind for this.  Start and end anchors would be enough: `^[^'](\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)?.*$` http://regex101.com/r/aB5xP3

Comment: Just to make it clear that I want to completely avoid the comment lines in my result but not single quote and still get the rest of the sentence. Hope it makes sense. I just tried a negative lookbehind as suggested but it just avoids single quote but gives me the second line which I don't want. The regEx I used is `(^(?!').)*(\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)`

Comment: No. Basically I want to extract Access Specifiers, Variable Name and Datatype from any vb code line that is not a comment line (because a comment line can have the matching expression)

Comment: I think I got little closer but still needs some help. Here is the regular expression to avoid comment lines in vb code:- (?<!'\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+) Now I am able to avoid the comment lines but can't extract the access specifiers for other valid lines. For instance, I can't extract "Public" string from line 1 of previously provided code. Kindly help

Comment: I got the answer. The regular expression is:- `(?<!'\w*)(\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)'

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!\s*')(\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)
```

Here it is checking using negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\s*')`, whether there is not any `'` character at the beginning of the line with optional multiple white-spaces(`\s*`).

I don't know `VB.Net`, so try this at [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cU8fJ3).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^[^'](\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)
```

Comment: I think I got little closer but still needs some help. Here is the regular expression to avoid comment lines in vb code:-

    `(?<!'\w*) Const (\w+) As (\w+)`

Now I am able to avoid the comment lines but can't extract the access specifiers for other valid lines. For instance, I can't extract "Public" string from line 1 of previously provided code. Kindly help